# copyfile error string vs. char

Tags: string, matlab, char, file-copying

I am trying to create a MATLAB loop where I can copy all the files listed in a txt file sent to me by a colleague from one directory on my computer to another.

The code I am using is:

```
FileList=textread('C:\Users\Desktop\list.txt','%s')

%copy files in list from one folder to another
cd ('C:\Users\source_directory')

for n=1:numel(FileList)
source=FileList(n)
destination='C:\Users\destination_directory'
copyfile(source,destination)
end
```

I keep getting this error:
"Error using copyfile
Argument must contain a string."

My FileList is a cell character array, but I also cannot convert to a string. When I try I get this:

> > string(FileList)
> >     Warning: string is obsolete and will be discontinued.
> >              Use char instead. 
> >     Error using string
> >     Conversion to char from cell is not possible.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: You need to use curly braces to get the character array from the cell array: `source = FileList{n}`

Comment: I've flagged an appropriate duplicate.  The problem you are experiencing is that you are not accessing the cell array correctly as noted by gnovice.  You use parentheses (i.e. `()`) to **slice** into a cell array.  The output would be another cell array.  To access the raw contents, you must use curly braces (i.e. `{}`).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked!